# Option "Merge all pages and controll outputs to a single assembly" still produces 100s of compile files

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, precompile

I have an MVC web application that I would like to deploy on a webserver. To improve performance and prevent tampering of the website, I have set the following options:

**Connection:**
`Publish method: File System`
`Target location: C:\builds\PROJECTNAME`

**Settings:**
`Delete all existing files prior to publish: Yes`
`Precompile during publishing: Yes`
`Exclude files from the App_Data folder: No`

**Advances Precompile Settings:**
`Allow the precompiled site to be updatable: No`
`Emit debug information: No`

**Merge options:**
`Selected: Merge all pages and control outputs to a single assembly`
`Name: BigAss_PROJECTNAME`

When the building is done, I have the various DLL's needed by the Framework, our DevExpress components and so on, but also 130 DLL's with names like 'App_Web_22vyifjz.dll'.

Furthermore, I have 1241 .compiled files in the bin folder with names like '_createandedit.cshtml.3b4d6ffa.compiled' which seems to match the cshtml files in the solution.

I understand that the various `.cshtml files` with the content "*This is a marker file generated by the precompilation tool, and should not be deleted!*" remain, but all those `DLL's` and `.compile files` are not wanted.

Is there any way to prevent this? Am I missing an option somewhere?

Comment: That is already set to false.

Comment: If you're wanting to reduce down to just a single (or few) files, wouldn't `merge all outputs` be a better option than `merge all pages and control outputs`

Comment: Even then I have lots of .compiled files which don't seem very usefull to me :)